# Priority Queue not sorting in right order

Tags: c++, multithreading, linked-list, priority-queue

So I am trying to build a priority queue that takes in 2 numbers (0 and 2). Values with priority 0 are to be added at the back of queue based on time of arrival. Priority 2's are to be inserted ahead of priority 0 packets but not ahead of already queued priority packets. without using std::priority_queue please. It is also a requirement to use Linked-Lists Can someone point out what im doing wrong? sample packet (bolded is priority):

55555555555555D507E34B17887100A0FF1822198100**0**100000663727970746fC704DD7B

```
 pQueue100::pQueue100(){
    front = NULL;
}

void pQueue100::insert(string packet, int priority)
{
    node2 *temp, *q;
    temp = new node2;
    temp ->info= packet;
    temp ->priority = priority;
    if (front == NULL ||priority <front->priority)
    {
        temp->link =front;
        front = temp;
    }else 
    {
        q = front;
        while (q->link != NULL && q->link->priority<=priority)
            q=q->link;
        temp->link = q->link;
        q->link=temp;
    }

    //display();
}//insert

void pQueue100::display()
{
    node2 *ptr;
    ptr = front;
    //node2 *temp;
    //temp = front;

    if (front ==NULL)
        cout << "Queue is empty" <<endl;
    else 
    {
        while (ptr != NULL)
        {
            ptr->priority;
            //temp->info;
            cout << ptr->priority << "|" ;
            cout << ptr->info <<endl;
            ptr = ptr->link;

        }
    }
}
```

If you guys want to see where the packets are coming from:

```
void thr1::selectPQueue(string packet){ //reads in packets from FIFO Queue and sorts it based on VLAN Tag and priority
    pQueue100 p100;
//  cout <<packet <<endl;//print packets for testing

    if (packet.substr(45,3) == "100"){ //if the packet matches VLAN 100....

        if (packet.substr(44,1) == "0"){
            priorityCode = 0;
        }else if (packet.substr(44,1) == "2"){
            notif = "!!!!!!!!!Priority Packet Packet Found: <..." + packet.substr(16,11) + "...> !!!!!!!!!";
            priorityCode = 2;
            packetCopy = packet;
            //thr2.interupptHandler(packetCopy, notif);
        }else
            priorityCode = priorityCode;

        p100.insert(packet, priorityCode);


    }//end VLAN 100

    else if (packet.substr(45,3) =="101") //if the packet matches VLAN 101
    {


        if (packet.substr(44,1) == "0"){
            priorityCode = 0;
        }else if (packet.substr(44,1) == "2"){
            notif = "!!!!!!!!!Priority Packet Packet Found: <..." + packet.substr(16,11) + "...> !!!!!!!!!";
            priorityCode = 2;
            packetCopy = packet;
            //thr2.interupptHandler(packetCopy, notif);

        }else
            priorityCode = priorityCode;
        //pQ101().recieveInterrupts(packet, priority,);

    }//end VLAN 101

    //p100.display();
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code line by line in a debugger, to see that it really does what you think it should do?

Comment: I think it has something  to do with

 while (q->link != NULL && q->link->priority<=priority)

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel ? You could just use `std::priority_queue` surely ?

Comment: You're not showing the class so we don't know the context of those member functions.  You shoukd study standard library and Boost code and learn how it works, not try to guess everything the experts knew, out of nothing.  There are some basic issues with the code shown.

Comment: @MajidAMannan: OK - you didn't mention that in the question.

Comment: @PaulR Sorry, forgot.

Comment: @JDługosz I hope you mean "study the standard library and Boost *interfaces*", as studying the implementation is something I wouldn't wish on my worst enemy. The big standard library and the Boost libraries implementations are mean, lean and effective, but not good to look at for someone just learning C++.

Comment: (1) why are you passing a string *by value*, making a needless copy?  (2) you are declaring temp and q (2a) both in one declaration, and (2b) without initializing them. (3) don't write explicit tests against NULL (more reciently, don't use NULL at all: use `nullptr`). (3) the constructor should use initializer syntax.  (4) without context it's hard to tell, but younare probably using pointers too directly within the class data, and not using constructors and encapsulation on this inner object. ...

Comment: On a higher level, I understand that implementing rather than using somone else's code is an exercise for learning (all the easy code's already been written). But, you are using a monolithic approach that does not factor into more basic components or work on top of general code.  You are implementing a *collection* at the same time as using a collection to keep your ordered values; you are hard-coding specific sort behavior rather than configuring general-purpose ordering behavior; you are using very primitive pointers, teats, and loops rather than *algorithms* to traverse and insert.

Comment: I suggest using a basic std collection like a vector or list as the foundation. If you were learning how to implement a linked list you would do *only* that, in a generic way, not mix it up with the usage of that list. IOW, a different exercise. Use std *algorithms* to insert your stuff in desired sorted order and use container's functions to extract.  You should not need to manipulate primitive pointers in the body of the data block, but I can't explain better without knowing what you have there.

Comment: Classically, a *priority queue* refers to a partly sorted collection that saves work by not keeping it in total order all the time. Maybe that is whatnyou are supposed to be writing?  But based on your desription you just need two FIFO queues.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg good point; things are harder to read then they were in 1989. There should be lesson material taking you through the most elementary implementations of basic now-canned things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple matter of reversing the comparison operators you've used.

```
void pQueue100::insert(string packet, int priority)
{
    node2 *temp, *q;
    temp = new node2;
    temp ->info= packet;
    temp ->priority = priority;
    if (front == NULL ||priority > front->priority)
    {
        temp->link =front;
        front = temp;
    }else 
    {
        q = front;
        while (q->link != NULL && q->link->priority >= priority)
            q=q->link;
        temp->link = q->link;
        q->link=temp;
    }
}
```

Driver code:

```
int main() 
{
    pQueue100 q;
    q.insert("alpha", 0);
    q.insert("beta", 2);
    q.insert("gamma", 0);
    q.insert("delta", 2);
    q.insert("epsilon", 0);
    q.insert("zeta", 2);
    // correct display sequence should be:
    // beta, delta, zeta, alpha, gamma, epsilon
    q.display();
}
```

Output:

```
2|beta
2|delta
2|zeta
0|alpha
0|gamma
0|epsilon
```